# Why does dd not output to stdout?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, cygwin, dd

**This is the command I am experiencing the issue with**

```
username@computer /current/working/directory
$ dd if="$filename" bs=1 seek=10 count=10 conv=notrunc status=progress^C
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 1.70242 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

**Test output to file trial (for sanity?)**

```
username@computer /current/working/directory
$ dd if="$filename" bs=1 seek=10 count=10 conv=notrunc status=progress of=test
22+0 records in
22+0 records out
22 bytes copied, 0.0115305 s, 1.9 kB/s
```

**Environment**

```
username@computer  /current/working/directory
$ echo $filename
somefile.ext

username@computer /current/working/directory
$ dd --version
dd (coreutils) 8.26
Packaged by Cygwin (8.26-1)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Paul Rubin, David MacKenzie, and Stuart Kemp.

username@computer /current/working/directory
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

username@computer /current/working/directory
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.5(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

username@computer /current/working/directory
$ stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
start = <undef>; stop = <undef>; lnext = ^Q;
-imaxbel
-echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

Relevant section from the `dd` Man page, which seems to imply outputting to the stdout file descriptor/stream is the default behavior:

```
      of=FILE
             write to FILE instead of stdout
```

Examples I have found such as in this link also imply that: [AskUbuntu - How do you monitor the progress of dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd#215590)

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Cygwin
- ConEmu 170517

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem might be with `seek` which tells `dd` to skip some blocks *at start of its output.* How do you expect it to work with `stdout`? In my Ubuntu the similar `dd` command also hangs until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Solution: get rid of the `seek=10` option and it should work.

Note: to skip the input use `skip`. Maybe this is what you really wanted.

Comment: Rats!  I knew about that distinction from recent, but got confused when leaving the parameter from an example that was writing to a file rather than reading one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5586379/1091943

Thanks!

Comment: Yup, changed it to `skip` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have the words "of=test" at the end of the line which is telling dd to write the output to a file "test" - delete that bit and it will write to stdout.

Comment: The command I am having trouble with was the first call to `dd` that is only lacking the `of=` parameter from the following invocation test, and shows no records were processed once I manually quit.  I have clarified some parts of the question text accordingly.